# Why do NMR spectrums have the higher chem shift values closer to x-axis?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

Im not understanding what the intuition is behind why the graph is represented so that the higher chem shift value is closer to x-axis (shouldnt it be the other way around?)

I understand that downfield = deshielded and will have higher ppm value which is closer to x-axis, but i dont understand why this is reversed to how an x/y graph is usually represented.? Thanks for any help

Comment: Just convention. There is no good reason for it as far as I know.

Comment: I heard about reversed scale with 10=0; 0=10 IIRC

Comment: @Mithoron that was the old tau scale.  The delta scale is an atrocity on the English language, because we talk about higher shifts as more deshielded, leading to implicit double negatives when comparing alkanes to alkenes for example.  As a side-note we don't usually call that the x-axis when referring to NMR.

Comment: The chemical shift axis *is* the $x$-axis. I don’t understand your question.

Answer (score 3):

This convention stems from historical reasons only. In the early days of NMR, there were a number of different ways to report NMR data; values for 'shielding constants' of nuclei was of most interest, rather than what we commonly refer to as chemical shifts. The two most common scales were the tau and delta scales . The tau scale had the chemical shifts running in the opposite direction, with increasing shielding constants running from left to right.

A third scale, the sigma scale was very commonly used, especially in heteronuclear analyses, and again had the shielding constant increasing to the right. This scale was favoured often by theorists, as it was usually a direct measurement of the shielding constant.

A mixture of tau and delta values was regularly seen in the literature up until IUPAC made their initial recommendations, in 1970. This was to adopt the delta scale, and report chemical shift relative to TMS at delta 0ppm, as values of chemical shift, which are dimensionless and, hence, field independent.